# Is it possible to dynamically access an object through a variable in TypeScript file in Angular 9?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In Typescript, you can access an Objects property dynamically using '[]'

That is:

`Object[VariableName]`

But what I want to know is that is it possible to access an object dynamically such as:

`[objectVariableName]click()`

That is 'click()' being a function of the dynamic variable 'objectVariableName'

TIA!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow . add a stackblitz.com sample to ask question otherwise it is flagged sooner or latter to be removed due to quality issues.

Comment: please post some more code.

Comment: use `this[objectVariableName].click()` if give you error `(this[objectVariableName] as any).click()`